Using requests I get a 401 but urllib3 and curl work
The following urllib code works to connect to the  using the :
import urllib3
import json

# Initialize a PoolManager instance
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

# Define the URL, headers, and data
url = "https://<url>"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
data = {
    "name": "some_test"
}

# Encode data to JSON
encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')

# Send the POST request
response = http.request(
    'POST',
    url,
    body=encoded_data,
    headers=headers
)

# Print the response status and data
print(response.status)
print(response.data.decode('utf-8'))

I also tried connecting via this CURL command which works:
curl -X "POST" "https://<url>" \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
    -d $'{
  "name": "some_test"
}'

But using the requests module the code returns a 401 message -> Unauthorized:
import requests


url = "<url>"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
data = {
    "name": "some_test"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)

I tried different requests version but all behave the same. What am I missing? Could it be a different conflict?

The answer was simple after reading this in the docs (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

Authorization headers set with headers= will be overridden if
credentials are specified in .netrc, which in turn will be overridden
by the auth= parameter. Requests will search for the netrc file at
~/.netrc, ~/_netrc, or at the path specified by the NETRC environment
variable.

After removing the .netrc it is working. I wonder however why the token can't be define in the .netrc but this is out of the scope of this question.
